# What is making this script not work?

Tags: javascript, html

This script is supposed to take the value from the form element with the id = measurement and is supposed to put that as the value of a dynamically created input that will be put within a table cell.

HTML:

```
<form name="addFood">
 <input type="number" name="measurement" id="measurement" size="20" style="width:30px">
 <button id="button" onclick="addItem()">Add Ingredient</button>
</form>

<table id="recipeItems">
</table>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
        function addItem(){
          var f = document.getElementsByName("addFood")[0];
          var x = document.getElementById("measurement").value;

          var table = document.getElementById("recipeItems");
          var row = table.insertRow(0);

          var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
          var meas = document.createElement("input");
          meas.type="number";
          meas.value=x;
          cell1.appendChild(meas);
        }
      </script>
```

Comment: first line is not used in this method, are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: Looks like it works. What's the problem?

Comment: the problem is that when I click the button, the dynamically created input box shows up for a second, then disappears

Comment: The `<form>` will be submitted when you click the `<button>`, which causes the page to navigate to a fresh copy of itself, with the `<table>` once again empty. To avoid submitting, you can give the button `type="button"`. Otherwise, the script seems to be working fine – https://jsfiddle.net/d9u81gq2/.

Answer (score 0):

As @Jonathan Lonowski  mentioned, when you put `button` in a form, it will try to submit the form, which will refresh the page or post the details.

If you want to stick to the same HTML, then you can add

```
event.preventDefault();
```

at the top the function. Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/t9fh989p/1/

Refer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault.

Otherwise, setting `type="button"` should do the job as well.